# App store homepage image

Tags: iphone, image, app-store, itunes

I uploaded an app to my country's app store, and it reached first place in top free in just 2 days!

Well, I am not bragging, since nobody here cares anyway :p

BUT! I think my app deserves to have a picture on the home page (the large image that previews applications in a 600x300 pixel rectangle [the size is approximate :P] )

Where can I include my design in the next update, so apple could see it and consider posting it?

what is the size?

(is my question even clear? :p)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an app that does very well, Apple will contact you and ask that you prepare special images for the App Store homepage. This [blog post](http://www.ideashower.com/blog/iphone-developers-prepare-featured-artwork-ahead-of-time/) lists out the specs as of August 31st, 2009.

It looks like you'll need to prepare two images: a 600x600 title treatment, and a 900x530 layered PSD for the background treatment. (This is the file you see rotating around on the app store background.)

From the post:

> **Title Treatment**
>
> This is a 600 x 600 image of your
>   logo/title.  The background should be
>   transparent and it should exclude
>   tag-lines if the text will not be
>   legible at a small scale.
>
> **Background Treatment**
>
> This is a 900 x
>   530 layered PSD.  What you put in this
>   file is fairly open.  Apple states: 
>   “The background image, texture, color
>   or gradient should correspond to the
>   application or compliment the title
>   treatment. It may include elements of
>   the application itself, but should not
>   be or include screenshots.”

EDIT:

I did some searching, and found that these dimensions still apply today, and are listed in Apple's Developer Guide. To find this, go into [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) and click the [Download the Developer Guide](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) link at the bottom of the page. You'll find the information on promotional artwork on pages 173 and 174.

Comment: when I was uploading my app for the first time, I remember reading an optional requirement of an image for homepage in case the app does well AND it looked nice... any idea?

Comment: I've uploaded a couple of games in the past week, and don't remember seeing an option to actually upload that artwork... I do have a contact at Apple who asked me to prepare these graphics, and she indicated that the usual process is: a) Apple will contact you directly to ask for this stuff, and b) you submit the artwork to Apple via email. The actual email address, for when the time comes, is artwork@apple.com.

Comment: hmmm... I must have been dreaming or something :p. Thanks!

Comment: Is this answer still valid in 2012? Or did anything change?

And what are the sizes for iPad?

Thank you

Comment: Dimensions changed, not sure when, but you need to provide much larger images nowadays, 3200x600 for background, 2004x586 for title. I am sure there will be more details in documentation somewhere

Comment: 2013 requirements listed here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/18_BestPractices/BestPractices.html